# Output to multiple audio devices on Chromebook?

Tags: google-chrome-os

I'd like to watch some movies on my Chromebook and have separate headphones for both me and my partner.

Is it possible to have audio output to two separate devices in Chrome OS?

Answer (score -1):

Chromebooks can pair with multiple devices via Bluetooth. Here is the process:

- Step 1: Check if your Chromebook works with Bluetooth

  - At the bottom right, select the time.
  - If you see Bluetooth Bluetooth, your Chromebook works with Bluetooth.
- Step 2: Pair a Bluetooth accessory

  - If Bluetooth is off, turn on Bluetooth.
  - Select the accessory you want to connect to.
  - Follow the onscreen instructions to finish connecting.
  - To check if your accessory is connected, look under "Paired devices."

**References**

- [Connect to Bluetooth devices - Chromebook Help](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/2587653?hl=en)
- [How to pair Bluetooth accessories with your Chromebook | Android Central](https://www.androidcentral.com/how-pair-bluetooth-accessories-your-chromebook)

Comment: This shows connecting multiple devices, but it doesn't actually answer the question that was asked, which is whether you can output audio to two devices simultaneously.